# Publishing updates to Android Apps

Tags: android, keystore

I published an App a while back and would like to make updates to it.  I've saved my password and Alias when i originally created the App but when i try export the App using the "Android Tools/Export Signed Application" option using Eclipse it prompts me for an existing Keystore. The only Keystore i can find is a debug.keystore in my .android folder under C:\Users\Username. I know you cant publish Apps on the Marketplace using the debug keystore. Does this mean i need to generate a new one from scratch using the existing Alias and password? 
If so, is there an option in eclipse to do this??

Answer (score 2):

You need the same key. If you really lost it, unfortunately you'll have to republish that app under a different name/key. If you use the wizard in ADT, it'll prompt you to generate a new key (or hopefully find your old one in some directory that you didn't check).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Does the Keystore file get saved into the same directory as the debug one i.e. the .android folder?

Comment: It prompts you to pick a filename/directory, so usually not the .android folder.

Comment: Check your /bin directory. My app originally defaulted to save my keystore there. Unfortunately it will periodically get delated if you do save it there. Always create backups and backups of backups of all this kind of vital data.

If you do have to republish, you can unpublish you're old one and republish under the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the same key, and wont be able to publish to the same application without it.

You can generate new ones via:
Using File -> Export -> Export Android Application, then follow the steps can generate a new one.